# how to implement jquery function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-3.5

I have ckeditor in application for implement html rich text. Here I just want to implement one function that calls while user want to upload image from ckeditor.

Here I just use Upload.ashx for save this file to images named folder. Here for implementing to upload files from web user control.

I use this function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () 
{
 CKEDITOR.replace('<%=CKEditor1.ClientID %>',{ filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/EasyWeb/Upload.ashx' })
;});
</script>
```

But that time my other functionality like jquery searching and expanding and collapsing jquery doesn't work properly.

How ever I remove this line then all works perfectly.

what is the problem...

**--------------------------------Updated---------------------------------------**

ya i found that one error like

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
CKEDITOR.replace('<%=CKEditor1.ClientID %>',{ filebrowserImageUploadUrl:  '/EasyWeb/Upload.ashx' }); //path to “Upload.ashx”
    });
</script>
```

Comment: check the console is there any error

Comment: @Nish ya i updated my question. and i found error like Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined from chrome console.

Comment: so your CKEditor js is not loading that's why you are getting that error.Keep above code on document.ready() then check may be it will work.

Comment: @Nish ya i follow ur steps but still i'm getting error.

Comment: @Nish ya i found that at Page_Load time i hide this panel Panel_Add_New panel this panel contains this ckeditor so this script doesn't found ckeditor with this id. so it throws error like Undefined CKEditor.